# How can you limit the speed of .map() for the sake of fetch()?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, rate-limiting, array.prototype.map

I'm working on an app where I need to .map() over some wallets, and in the process use the wallet data to make a fetch call, then return a new object with the original wallet data spread into it and finally add the new information from the fetch. (Getting a balance from [https://btc1.trezor.io/api/v2/xpub/{my-btc-xpub}](https://btc1.trezor.io/api/v2/xpub/%7Bmy-btc-xpub%7D))

I am running into an issue where .map() hits the fetch calls so fast, that it causes it to fail on the 2nd item.

I've found just placing the fetch in the a setInterval() with 1000 ms is plenty of time for it to fetch repeatedly.

**However**, setInterval() with 500ms is reproducing the same 503 error my .map() fetch()es have been returning to me.

All of my code works until I've added a second wallet to my database, causing the map to run at least twice.

Is there a way to regulate how fast these fetch()es will be made? Is there a better way of going about this problem?

Related working code:

```
setInterval(() => {
    fetch(`https://btc1.trezor.io/api/v2/xpub/${xpub}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
}, 1000)
```

Related broken code:

```
    static async getWalletBalances(_accountsList) {
        try {
            let accountPromises = _accountsList.map(async account => {
                let walletPromises = account.wallets.map(async wallet => {
                    //breaks right here!!!
                    let balance = await fetch(`https://btc1.trezor.io/api/v2/xpub/${wallet.walletXpub}`)
                         /*
                         this response becomes a 503 html page response instead of json
                         after the first wallet data is fetched
                         */
                        .then(response => response.json())
                        .then(data => data.balance)
                    return { ...wallet, balance: balance }

                })

                let wallets = await Promise.all(walletPromises)
                return { ...account, wallets: wallets }
            })

            let accountsList = await Promise.all(accountPromises);
            return accountsList

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Unable to fetch balances: ${error}`)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This isn't your problem but the API should really be responding with a [429](https://http.cat/429) if you're exceeding the rate limit. If you can communicate that back to them, it would make the response easier to deal with for you and others

Comment: using `for` loops instead of `.map` will make this code simple - and if you'd rather mutate the passed in `_accountsList` rather than returning a new `accountsList` it's even simpler